# How can I compare the value of the list with the other values from the same list?

Tags: python, list

I'm working on my code. I want to know which value is greater than a list by comparing each value contained in the list. The following is an example of the list I created.

```
list = ['1192:09:05', 1, -60, 5, -79, 4, -24, ..., n, n+1]
```

Based on that list, I want to know the the greatest one between `list[2] list[4] list[6] list[n+1]`

Comment: Are you searching for the [`max`](/https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) function ?

Comment: Use `max([list[2], list[4], list[6], list[n+1]])`

Is there a specific patern of the elements you want to check (eg all with even idex, etc)?

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood, you want to know the max value of a list.

You can try this:

```
list = ['1192:09:05', 1, -60, 5, -79, 4, -24, ..., n, n+1]
```

The first element of this list must not be taken into consideration.

```
max = list[1]
for x in range(1,len(list)):
    if list[x] > max:
        max = list[x]
```

if you want to know the greatest number between list[2] list[4] list[6] list[n+1], you can make:

```
max = list[1]
for x in range(1,len(list),2):
    if list[x] > max:
        max = list[x]
```

I don't know what 'n' is, i can't help you with that.